# React Native Paper Snackbar is not closing

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I'm currently running into an issue, where my snackbar is opening, but is not going to close after invoking the context function.

Here's the context and the entire managment:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const snackBarReducer = createSlice({
  name: "snackbarAlert",
  initialState: {
    open:false,
    message:"",
    alertType:"",
  },
  reducers: {
    showMessage(state, action) {
        state.open=true;
        state.message=action.payload.message;
        state.alertType=action.payload.alertType ? action.payload.alertType : "";
    },
    hideMessage(state) {
    state.open=false;
    state.message="";
    }
  },
});

export const snackbarActions = snackBarReducer.actions;
```

Conditional showcase of screens and where the snackbar is being shown:

```
  const ScreenContainer = () => {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const {user}=useAuthContext();
  const alertType=useSelector((state)=>state.snackbarAlert.alertType);
  const isAlertOpen=useSelector((state)=>state.snackbarAlert.open);
  const alertMessage=useSelector((state)=>state.snackbarAlert.message);
    return (
<>
    {user ? <RootNavigation/> : <UnloggedNavigation/>}

    {isAlertOpen && <SnackbarAlert visible={isAlertOpen} snackbarText={alertMessage} snackbarType={alertType}/>}
</>
    
   )
}
```

And the snackbar component over here:

```
import { Snackbar } from 'react-native-paper';

import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import {
  darkRed,
  spotify,
} from '../../assets/ColorsImport';
import { snackbarActions } from '../../context/SnackBarContext';

const SnackbarAlert = ({snackbarText, snackbarType, visible}) => {
const appropriateStyles=snackbarType==="error" ? {backgroundColor:darkRed, fontFamily:"Inter-Black"} : {backgroundColor:spotify,fontFamily:"Inter-Black"}


return (
<Snackbar 
action={{
  label:"Close",
  labelStyle:{color:"white", fontFamily:"Inter-Black"},
  onPress:()=>(
    snackbarActions.hideMessage()),
  icon: ()=>(<FontAwesome name='close' size={16} color="white"/>)
}} style={appropriateStyles} duration={300} visible={visible} onDismiss={()=>(
  snackbarActions.hideMessage())}>
  {snackbarText}
</Snackbar>
  )
}

export default SnackbarAlert
```

I tried to do it also with normal useState, but it did not work.